# git merge squash not doing what I expect it to do

Tags: git

I am new to git and still learning. I would like to merge my branch to main, at the same time do a squash so that all the branches commits turn into one commit.
Right now I have a branch b and (master?) main. The commands I ran:

```
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout b
git merge master
#fixed conflicts
git add
git commit
git push
git checkout master
git merge --squash b
git push
```

give the output:

[image]

The result I imagined I would get is where I have everything on one line, something like this:

[image]

Please if not necessary do not go too deep into the explanation since I am getting more and more confused by the documentation, youtube and answers to questions similiar to mine.

Comment: `remotes/origin/b` ? Once you push changes to remote, it's (hard/impossible/bad) to change the history of the branch. The history of `main` looks more or less like you wanted. So you want to remove the branch `b` from local and remote I guess?

Answer (score 2):

It's useful, when using Git, to know what a command does *before* giving that command. A squash merge is *not a merge*, and it does *not* affect any existing commits. When you say this:

```
git merge --squash b
```

... that does *not* affect the branch being merged (`b`), and it does *not* affect the past history of the branch being merged to (`main`). It just embodies the joint history of the two branches as a *single new additional commit* on the branch you're on (`main`). But it doesn't actually *perform* that commit; it configures the index (staging area), but it's up to you to commit if you want it.

And that is what we see in your screen shot, so no big surprise. Here's what you did, and how it corresponds to the history in your screen shot:

```
git checkout main
git pull # "fourth commit from master", I presume
git checkout b
git merge master # diagonal line from "fourth commit from master" to b
# you hit a conflict at this point, fixed it by hand
git add # tells git that the conflict is resolved
git commit # finishes the merge: "fix merge"
git push # moved remotes/origin/b up to b
git checkout master
git merge --squash b # potentially created "squash merge with branch b"
# you must have said commit here?
git push # I don't see any sign that you actually did that
```

Perhaps what you *wanted* to do was merge `b` in a normal way (with fast-forward if possible) to `main`. You could *then* squash `main` backwards to form a single a commit after "second commit from master".

You could, in fact, just delete `b` now and *now* squash `main` backwards. You will lose all memory of `b` as a separate entity, but you will have a single commit on `main` after "second commit from master" that contains everything that was on `b` and everything that was in "third commit from master" and "fourth commit from master". That seems to be what you want (though it's hard to tell).

Comment: Thank you, both of your answers helped! Like I said, I am new to git so what im asking may not make full sense to you.